# VBA - send email with attachment

Tags: vba

From last week till now, I have a several question here to did the mini project send email with attachment by Excel VBA. Now I'm stucking in the final step.
My project is send email with the proper attachment (stored in the specific folder). something like this:

[image]
[image]

Here is my code:

```
Sub SendEmail_Example1()
' email processing

For i = 2 To Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Source As String
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

EmailItem.To = Sheet2.Range("D" & i).Value
'EmailItem.CC = "hello@gmail.com"
'EmailItem.BCC = "hhhh@gmail.com"
EmailItem.Subject = "User info of " & Sheet2.Range("D" & i).Value
EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hi, below is your user info " & "<br>" & "User is: " & Sheet2.Range("B" & i).Value & "<br>" & _
"Password is : " & vbNewLine & Sheet2.Range("C" & i).Value & _
vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"<br>" & "Regards," & _
"<br>" & "VT"
'Source = ThisWorkbook.FullName
'---------Attachment
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Dim file As file
Dim folder As folder
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\test")
'Source = "C:\test"
For Each file In folder.Files
    If Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value = file.Name Then
        
        EmailItem.Attachments.Add file.Name
        Exit For
        
    End If
Next file
    
EmailItem.Send
Next i
End Sub
```

I would like to grab the proper attachment with each outgoing email, that mean the email send to user named "jack" will get the attach named "jack.xlsx"

[image]

Could you please help assist on this issue ? Appriciated much for all the support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues with FSO/Attachment portion of your code:

1. `file.Name` will return the file with the extension which will not match the value in your Column A so you need to use `fso.GetBaseName` to get the file name without the extension.
2. You need to provide the full path of the file to add attachment so use `file.Path` instead of `file.Name`.

   ```
   Dim fso As FileSystemObject
   Set fso = New FileSystemObject
   Dim file As file
   Dim folder As folder
   Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\test")
   'Source = "C:\test"
   For Each file In folder.Files
       If Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value = fso.GetBaseName(file.Name) Then

           EmailItem.Attachments.Add file.Path
           Exit For

       End If
   Next file

   EmailItem.Send
   ```